# How to make lazy loader work on home page images(thumbnail) of blog

Tags: javascript, blogger

I am using lazy loader code snippet for a web page which works fine for post body images but it not working for thumbnail images on home page of a site. Please can you help me to customize this code by which it can work perfectly to the thumbnail on homepage of a site. The java script code i used is this

```js
     <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[   
  (function(a){a.fn.lazyload=function(b){var c={threshold:0,failurelimit:0,event:"scroll",effect:"show",container:window};if(b){a.extend(c,b)}var d=this;if("scroll"==c.event){a(c.container).bind("scroll",function(b){var e=0;d.each(function(){if(a.abovethetop(this,c)||a.leftofbegin(this,c)){}else if(!a.belowthefold(this,c)&&!a.rightoffold(this,c)){a(this).trigger("appear")}else{if(e++>c.failurelimit){return false}}});var f=a.grep(d,function(a){return!a.loaded});d=a(f)})}this.each(function(){var b=this;if(undefined==a(b).attr("original")){a(b).attr("original",a(b).attr("src"))}if("scroll"!=c.event||undefined==a(b).attr("src")||c.placeholder==a(b).attr("src")||a.abovethetop(b,c)||a.leftofbegin(b,c)||a.belowthefold(b,c)||a.rightoffold(b,c)){if(c.placeholder){a(b).attr("src",c.placeholder)}else{a(b).removeAttr("src")}b.loaded=false}else{b.loaded=true}a(b).one("appear",function(){if(!this.loaded){a("<img />").bind("load",function(){a(b).hide().attr("src",a(b).attr("original"))[c.effect](c.effectspeed);b.loaded=true}).attr("src",a(b).attr("original"))}});if("scroll"!=c.event){a(b).bind(c.event,function(c){if(!b.loaded){a(b).trigger("appear")}})}});a(c.container).trigger(c.event);return this};a.belowthefold=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).height()+a(window).scrollTop()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().top+a(c.container).height()}return d<=a(b).offset().top-c.threshold};a.rightoffold=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).width()+a(window).scrollLeft()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().left+a(c.container).width()}return d<=a(b).offset().left-c.threshold};a.abovethetop=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).scrollTop()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().top}return d>=a(b).offset().top+c.threshold+a(b).height()};a.leftofbegin=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).scrollLeft()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().left}return d>=a(b).offset().left+c.threshold+a(b).width()};a.extend(a.expr[":"],{"below-the-fold":"$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","above-the-fold":"!$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","right-of-fold":"$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","left-of-fold":"!$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})"})})(jQuery);$(function(){$("img").lazyload({placeholder:"https://i22.servimg.com/u/f22/15/42/72/40/grey10.gif",effect:"fadeIn",threshold:"-50"})})//]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script did not work. Why you not using native html lazy load ? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading) -> scroll to Images and iframes block.